# Spark Notebook Oops, an error occured

Tags: scala, spark-notebook

I downloaded spark notebook from http://spark-notebook.io/. I have spark-notebook-0.7.0-scala-2.10.6-spark-2.0.1-hadoop-2.7.2. It works on my laptop where I have Ubuntu 14.04. But the same notebook doesn't run on my desktop where I also have Ubuntu 14.04. The server runs but on the browser (http://localhost:9001/), it shows Oops, an error occured
This exception has been logged with id 75mgeof4j (screenshot attached). [image: spark notebook error message]